# Problem with double Fedora installation. mount: /boot/efi: unknown filesystem type 'vfat'. Possible overwritten installation

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, uefi

Some days ago, I decided to install Fedora 33 Jam on an empty partition (sda6) I had created when I installed Fedora 32 Workstation (on sdb1) a couple of years ago. With the intention to finish with both systems in a dual-boot, I selected the sda6 partition to mount '/', and an existing small partition in sda1 labeled as '/boot', to mount /boot/EFI for the new Fedora 33 Jam. The thing is that this '/boot' partition in sda1 already had the /boot/EFI of the 1st OS, Fedora 32 WS. Now, when Grub appears, it shows both systems, but Fedora 32 fails to boot and enters in emergency mode. Fedora 33 Jam boots and works perfectly fine. Booting from Fedora 33 Jam, I've checked the partitions of the Fedora 32 system: if I mount Fedora 32's root '/', located in sdb1, I can 'cd' to /boot, and see that the Fedora 32 kernel initramfs images, vmlinuz files, grub2, etc., are still there, but the folders /boot/efi/EFI and /boot/efi/loader are empty. Another thing I could mention is that the entry in the Grub for Fedora 32 WS system loads the rescue image (I'm able to see that by pressing 'e' to edit that entry).

Regarding the errors that appear in the log when Fedora 32's boot finishes in emergency mode, the errors that I can see from the /var/log/boot.log file (in sdb1) are the following:

- Failed to start Load Kernel Modules
- Failed to mount FUSE Control File System
- Failed to mount /boot/efi
- Failed to mount Mount unit for core, revision 10185
- Failed to mount Mount unit for hello-world, revision 29
- Failed to mount Mount unit for openboard, revision 14

Also, I could see the following problem from the emergency mode terminal, in the output of 'systemctl status boot-efi.mount':
mount: /boot/efi: unknown filesystem type 'vfat'

Just for reference, this is the /etc/fstab file content corresponding to the Fedora 32 installation:
[image]

And this is the fstab content of the new Fedora 33 Jam installation:
[image]

You can see there that both systems have the same physical partition for their /boot/efi...

Any suggestion or hint on how to fix this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I use Ubuntu, but believe Fedora is the same. Do not confuse ESP - efi system partition which is FAT32 with /boot partition or folder in / which if separate partition is ext2 or other Linux format. Fedora often uses LVM and then does have ESP, /boot & partition for LVM  volumes. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I see the difference between the partition for /boot/efi (vfat format) and the boot folder in '/' (esp format). When I installed Fedora 32 two years ago, I labeled as '/boot' the vfat partition for /boot/efi. Now I can see that it's confusing. I've just edited my original post with the fstab content to clarify that.
Here's the paste of the boot report: https://pastebin.com/G55g4AC7
The Boot-info tool is not available in Fedora. I've found this script (https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/files/bootinfoscript/0.61/) to get boot info. I hope it's OK.

Comment: It looks like your sdb is just a 22GB drive. Did you reuse the other system folders like /var? You can share ESP, but only one system will be in UEFI to boot & then grub would show the other install.  But you cannot share other system partitions without overlap & issues.

Comment: That's correct. My laptop has 2 discs: a 22GB SSD and a 500GB HDD. I originally installed **Fedora 32** mounting '/' in the SSD, and ''/home', '/var' and '/tmp' in different partitions in the HDD. The new **Fedora 33** installation is completely located into the sda6 partition in the HDD, and so are the /var, /tmp, folders for that system. The only partition that was (unfortunately) set for both systems is sda1 in the HDD, which has '/boot/efi'. That is what I'm trying to fix... I don't know if the setup I made for the other partitions is somehow problematic.

Comment: If its just the ESP, have you run repairs on it? Must be unmounted
`sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sdXY` where sdXY is drive & partition of ESP. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=164185 And if other partitions are ext4 and having issue, you may need fsck. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: Yes, I tried running Rescatux on the sda1 partition, but it fails at the last step. I'll try your suggestion. I have a question about it: can I try the repair using the new installed Fedora 33 (which is booting and working perfectly) or I need to do it from a live USB?

Comment: Partitions have to be unmounted, so if ESP, you need live installer as it is mounted and not sure if you can unmount it without issue. Other partitions that are not mounted can be run from your working install. From your working install the old installs /boot/efi folders would be empty as they are only mounted when booting.

Comment: It worked :) Now I see that the folder '/boot/loader/entries' of the old Fedora 32 in sdb1 contains four .conf files (including the rescue one). Those files weren't there before... Now I have to change the entries in the Grub, since when it starts, it only shows the entry corresponding to the rescue image (which leads to emergency mode), and the entry to the newest kernel is the last option appearing in "Advanced options for Fedora 32...". Thanks a lot for your help!